# Add Datamasking on table

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, data-masking

I wanted to mask my table with any masking technique. From some sources, tried some on sql*plus but shows an error as shown below. Is it possible without pl/SQL? How to perform it directly on the command line?

SQL:

```
create table test1 (id int, name varchar2(10) MASKED with (function = 'default()');
create table test1 (id int, name varchar2(10) MASKED with (function = 'default()')
                                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: I don't think there is a MASKED with criteria in oracle.

Comment: So how can I mask my table in oracle?